# How to capture the interactive response of sudo command?

Tags: linux, shell, sudo

I have written a shell script to install a software. But it has interactive console. Say, type Yes/No.

**Command : sudo ./downloaded_software.run**

Shell script will hve the above command (test.sh)

```
Response of a command:    
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Welcome to the Setup Wizard.

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Select the components you want to install; clear the components you do not want 
    to install. Click Next when you are ready to continue.

     Core Files [y/N] :
```

Like this, there are three interactive responses to be handled (Y , Y and press [Enter]). How do i do it ?

Comment: I didn't follow your question, you want to create interactive installation of your software by user? you want to know how to do this in Linux ubuntu?

Comment: Describe what you mean by "capture".

Comment: @LethalProgrammer: In manual procedure, i could see these interactive prompts. I want to know how do i handle it (automated / via shell script).

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: I meant 'capture' as above pasted response. My idea is to capture that response and the pass the desired keys (Y, N , '[ENTER]').

Comment: Whereas in automated way its different. I presume your installing *.deb package. In debian system you can write a script where you do `sudo apt get install yoursoftware` it will install. If you want to automate your script for the installation, you can make shell script as service script where your application process up and running, it can trigger the script for installation.

Comment: @Jackie Why would you want to first make an interactive program and then automate it? If you want it to work in a non interactive fashion, make your program accept command line arguments for the various questions or run off a script that has pre defined responses. The interactive mode can be optionally enabled using a flag.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer : sudo apt get install doesn't work. I'm trying to automate the installation of XAMP server on Linux.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim :I'm trying to install XAMP server on Linux via script. Is there any way to pass arguments and make it as single command to complete installation without any interaction.

Comment: Pipe the output of `yes` into your script? `su` to root and then `yes | downloaded_software.run`

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

We can install in `'silent'` mode, known as 'Silent Installation'.

```
sudo ./downloaded_software.run --mode unattended
```

This will not prompt the user for any information.